# What does it mean that if particular wallet has more of particular erc20 token than ever recieving it via transactions? How dit it get there?

Tags: erc-20

I know this is basic question, but would like to know answer anyway :-) Example is here:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x4dc3643dbc642b72c158e7f3d2ff232df61cb6ce?a=0xd56b96cf1856f839a8fe9b1431ff2b0a782f0e80

This address recieved 5000 tokens, but ballance is 10000, was it some token generation event?

Comment: interesting. Do you know of any other examples of such non-standard contracts? I would like to look into it.

Comment: according to the source code this token is being minted , depending on the different sale phase. `Minted` event is not show by Etherescan, so probably this is the reason for the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transfer list will only show transfers that correspond to a `Transfer` event from the token contract.

Some not-so-well-written contracts often don't emit a Transfer event for the initial distribution or airdrop set up, which leads to addresses having more tokens than can be tracked via the Transfer logs.

Additionally, tokens can also be allocated via the `Mint` functionality, as appears to be the case here. Again, since these don't involve a `Transfer` event, they won't show up in the transaction list.